# Changing URL params to query params - Cloudflare rules

Tags: cloudflare

I'm trying to add a Cloudflare URL Rewrite Transform Rule so that users that come to my blog using this link: "https://example.com/myfirstblog" (dynamic path) get redirected to "https://example.com/?blogPage=myfirstblog"

I've tried looking at the docs and using this in the expression editor, but to no avail.

`(http.request.uri.path ne "" and not http.request.uri.path contains "/static")`